# Unable to set cookies in local machine

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

i want to set cookies to the webpage, the webpage with extension .php has this content

```
<?php
setcookie("engineer","engineer",time()+3600);
?>
<html>
<img src= "image3.jpg"  height="300" width="300"/>
</html>
```

i created a apache2 server in my ubantu virtual machine, and placed the above file with name `test.php` in the `/var/www/html` folder and tried to access the website, the website got opened but the cookie was not set :( i don't the reason why cookie has not set. i tried some answers from stackoverflow but still not able to set cookie anyone help me in this
Here is what i tried

1. added the '/' for path

   `setcookie("engineer","engineer",time()+3600,'/');`
   but still not able to setcookie
2. uninstalled and reinstalled the apache2 server but still same issue.
3. also tried by removing time() in that line
   `setcookie("engineer","engineer",3600);`

Comment: "cookie has not set" means that you didn't get the HTTP header or that the browser ignored it?

Comment: header has came i mean the image attached was visible , but cookie was not set

Comment: i found that cookie was not set up with cookie editor extension in the firefox and i also confirmed that the cookie was not set by performing wireshark packet capture

Comment: you need to specify the domain and path, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php you are missing some parts to setcookie()

Comment: @RyanH i read that php manual too, in the first example they didn't use the domain for that , and i tried giving the path which is '/'

Comment: @RyanH many videos i saw in youtube they are using the same format i used but i could not get it :(

Comment: @gurukiranx from the docs `Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie expires. Expire time is set via the expires parameter. A nice way to debug the existence of cookies is by simply calling print_r($_COOKIE);.`  look at the actual network request in your browsers debugger and look at the header that was sent from your server to verify that the header was transmitted.

Comment: To set a baseline, [this is the HTTP header](https://i.imgur.com/0oEkREn.png) I see in my browser's Network pane (F12). It then shows up in the [cookie pane](https://i.imgur.com/HPPG6bD.png). And finally the browser sends a [different header on **next** requests](https://i.imgur.com/fbufKlb.png). Can you please go through these steps and see when your workflow stops working?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thank you so much for your time but the main thing is i didn't install the php at all. i found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after so much of searching in internet i found the solution,
the main thing you need to display a php page is first you need to install the php, to install php use this command

`$ sudo apt-get install php`

after installing php you need to type this command

`$ sudo a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif`

`$ sudo service apache2 restart`

here is [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)